# Make scroll content scrolling at both axes with Flash Scrollpane Component (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I would like to scroll content in a Movie Clip (size: 10000 x 8000 px) with Flash Scrollpane component (AS3). However, I want to make the content scroll in both X & Y axis instead of along of the scrollbar axis. How can I achieve this?

I'm using Adobe Flash CS5 & AS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [ScrollPane](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/containers/ScrollPane.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) component ?

Comment: Yes, while Scrollbar Component is impossible to achieve this (as its source can only be a TextField), I changed the component to ScollPane.